# Remove session Id from URL

Tags: magento-1.9, api, url, session

My website has only one store,some times when hitting URL its shows SID with URL, I want to remove session Id from URL.I know  there is admin setting to display in frontend. My store has some API based on front end controller and  when I am setting show SID on frontend to NO ,my mobile APIs are not working properly because they are using session Id , is there a way where we can use SID but hide from URLs?

Answer (score 2):

You can remove the SID in two ways:

1. Go to your Magento admin panel > System > Configuration > Web.
   Under Session Validation Settings, set "No" against label 'Use SID on the Frontend".
   If this doesn’t work, then move to second option below.
2. Edit the file at app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App.php (somewhere around line 222),
   protected $_useSessionInUrl = true;
   Change that value to "false". That should now prevent session IDs appearing in URL.

Hope this will help you!

Answer (score -1):

Have you check the /app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App.php ? (probably line 227)

Change that value to “false” and try it again.

Comment: Thanks for reply ,its still shwoing on URL.check this https://www.fingoshop.com/?SID=lr1df3jtn3nrq98p35h1b53cu0

Comment: Maybe you can fix this with .htaccess.
Please have a look at here
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11300200/magento-sid-u-appearing-in-some-urls